# React: how to forward refs to multiple children?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to forward multiple refs to multiple children DOM nodes:
I need references to the 7 buttons, so I can manage focus between them.
I tried by using an array of `React.createRef()` and then attach each element of this array to a child using **index**, but all refs refers to the last button.
Why and is there another solution?

```js
class RestaurantsList extends Component {
  references = Array(7).fill(React.createRef());

  render() {
    return (
      <ul 
        id="restaurants-list"
        role="menu"
      >
        {
          this.props.restaurants.map((restaurant, index) => {
            return (
              <Restaurant 
                ref={this.references[index]}
                name={restaurant.name}
              />
            );
          })
        }
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

const Restaurant = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <li>
      <button 
        ref={ref}
      >
        {name}
      </button>
    </li>
  );
})
```

Comment: create array I guess(but not in `state` for sure). and maybe it'd be useful to add helper method `focusButton` to call outside

Comment: @skyboyer Once I have access to my laptop, I'll apply this idea and tell if it works, it makes sense to me. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hey @skyboyer, I edited the question to include my actual code.

Comment: I tried to use an array of refs, but for some reason all refs refer to the last dom node.

Comment: because `Array.fill()` does not evaluate `React.createRef()` per each element. Rather it is called just once and the same reference is put in every element of array

Comment: `Array(7).fill(0).map(() => React.createRef())` will work but I propose you go different way. Currently `<Restaurant>` is not provided with `key`(and React should complain about that at console) so you need some id field for `key` prop. If you have such a property then what if you keep refs as hashmap(`{ ... }`) where id is a key and ref is a value?

Comment: Thank you very much @skyboyer. You really helped me .. Please post an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As it was discussed in comments the best way is to keep list of references as an array or object property inside parent component.

As for `Array.prototype.fill()` its arguments is calculated just once. In other words `fill(React.createRef())` will generate list where each entry will refer to the same object - and you will get equal `ref` to last element. So you need to use `.map()` for getting unique reference objects.

```
references = Array(7).fill(0).map(() => React.createRef());
```

Anyway in real world project this will rather happen in `constructor()` or `componentDidUpdate()`.

But I believe it's better to have hashmap:

```
references = {};

getOrCreateRef(id) {
    if (!this.references.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
        this.references[id] = React.createRef();
    }
    return this.references[id];
}

render() {
    return (
    ....
    {
      this.props.restaurants.map((restaurant, index) => {
        return (
          <Restaurant 
            ref={this.getOrCreateRef(restaurant.id)}
            key={restaurant.id}
            name={restaurant.name}
          />
        );
      })
    }
```

Also you will need some helper methods to avoid exposing `this.references` to outer world:

```
focusById(id) {
    this.references[id].current && this.references[id].current.focus();
}
```

And take special attention to cleaning up references to unmounted elements. Otherwise you may got memory leak if list of restaurants is changed dynamically(if `ref` stays in `this.references` it keeps reference to HTML element even if it has been detached). Actual need depends on how is your component used. Also this memory leakage will be fixed once container(that has `reference = {}`) is unmounted itself due to navigating away.